# マニフェストに　照らした、審査、裁定を、お願いしても　いいものですか？

Tags: 討議

ご意見を　求めます。
"

確か、

此方貴兄方制定の　マニフェストでは、

できる　範囲での
最大限、

費解に　向けた、
努力をする　事を、
求めているか、

と　思います。
"

しかし、

》低評価理由は　文体である、
》読み難い、

との　意見が、
散見されます。
"

所で、

こうした　文体ならば、
正規表記置換できる　テキストエディタならば、
「、¥n」「　」
これらを　「」に、
置換すれば。
"

是否外では、

分と　かからず、
概ね　べた書き文章を、
得られます。
"

では、

此処で　伺いますね。
"

こうした、

・　テキストエディタを　起動せず、

・　分と　かからない、
　　作業を　行わない。

此等は。
"

貴兄方の、

マニフェストに　照らした、
場合、

どのような　答を、
導くべきですか？
"

勿論、

質問者は　指摘を、
受けて、

マニフェストに　照らし、
相互理解を　得る、
努力として、

・　説明をなす、

・　指摘者に、
　　提案や、説明を、
　　求める、

等々は　必須だ、
と、

私自身　反省しています。

Answer (score 5):

確かに分とかからず、作業自体はできます。
ですが、私だったらおそらくやらないです。

それはWebサイトという特性であり、
不特定多数の人が善意で運用しているサイトだからです。

（１）Webサイトの特性について
レスポンスタイムと回遊率や直帰率やコンバージョンの関係性は明確な関係性があります。
[参考](https://blog.ideamans.com/2019/03/web-performance-phrases.html)

コンマ数秒でユーザーエクスペリエンスが大きく変わる世界で
なぜテキストエディタを開いて、正規表現の置換をしなければいけないのでしょうか？

また、スマホやその他のデバイスを使っている場合PCより作業は難しくなるでしょう。

であれば質問自体を書き換えて読みやすくすれば
閲覧者にテキストエディタにコピーしてもらい、正規表現による置換の作業は不必要になります。

どっちのコストがいいのかはよく理解できると思います。

Be Niceを精神に合わせるならば、読みずらいと指摘される文章を直すことに専念したほうが良いでしょう。
そうすれば誰もテキストエディタを開かなくて済むし、正規表現の置換の作業も必要ないです。
作業をしたあなたのコストがちょっとかかっただけでほかの人のコストは0で済みます。

ではなんで、そんなにコンバージョンとか気にするの？というと
このコミュニティの[マニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)の「目標」に「検索エンジンにキーワードを入力することで、日本語で詳細に書かれた回答へのリンクが検索結果に表示される環境を整えること。」があります。
広く開かれた世界でできるだけ多くのプログラマに目に触れていただけるようなサイトを作る必要があります。他のプログラマが検索したときにこのサイトの回答が上部に来るようにする必要があります。
そのためにはほかの人に有益でわかりやすい情報を常に提供し続け、サイトの回遊率を上げて直帰率を下げ、より質問や回答をしてもらえるようにコンバージョン率を上げる必要があります。

（２）不特定多数の人が善意で運用しているサイト
ほとんどの人はマイナス投票もせずコメントも書かず何もしないで質問をスルーします。
実際私がこの回答をしているときは28件閲覧されたようですが投票はマイナス投票は3票プラスは0票でコメントは0で回答は0の状況です。つまりは行動を起こしてくれる人は10%程度です。
マイナス投票だけして帰るというのもそれも立派な善意の行動です。
われわれはそれを歓迎します。もちろんよりよくなるためには、コメントで指摘してもらうのが良いでしょう。回答していただける人がいればそれはもちろん大歓迎です。
そんな状況であるのにさらに、テキストエディタを開いて置換して、質問文をかみ砕いて読み解こうとする人がいたら無茶苦茶すごい人だと思います。ありがたい善意の行動ですね。
ですがそれをほかの人に求めてはいけないと思います。
他人に善意を求めてしまうともはや何が善意で何が強制なのかわかりません。
あくまで自分主体で善意を提供するべきで、相手から善意が求めれられないからといって相手に行動要求することはできません。

マイナス投票してくれているだけ善意だという意識であればいかにテキストを置換して読み直す作業がハードルが高いか理解できると思います。

Comment: 1/2

(1)
マニュフェスト中の、
一部を　恣意的に、
封鎖し、取り上げる、
とは。
"
"
抑も、
"
乗り上げるに　足りないと、
思います。
"
"
(2)
"
〉つまりは行動を起こしてくれる人は10%
"
詰まり、
"
不評を　示したのが、
10%であって、
其れ　以外の、
何らも　示し得ないもの。
"
"
元より、
"
論拠捏造なんて　こじつけでは?
"
"
〉不特定多数の人が善意で運用し
"
無関係事項。
"
"
マニュフェストを、
"
其の　方々自身が、
守る　事を、
決められたのですから。
"
"
ご都合"で、
"
常軌外に　一々、
枉げられては、
"
ルールによる　統治が、
崩れ。
"
"
連れて、
"
様々な　対処における、
正当さ、公正さ、正当性、
までもが　崩れます。
"
"
故、
"
最善な　表現として、
「無関係事項、」
とする　事が、
"
最善の　表しと、
なるでしょう。
"
"
もし、
"
貴方の　答申に、
沿えば、
"
マニュフェストより、
「私なら　如何するか、」が
優先の　事と、
なりますが。

Comment: 2/2
"
なら、
"
此方の　一切の、
ルールより、
「当人が　如何するかが、
優先、」
"
との　事と、
なりますよね。
"
"
限定執行として、
"
今回のみ、此処のみ、
と　して、
貴方の　方針に、
沿って、
"
貴方の　答申を、
無意味な　ものと、
裁定し、
却下と　致します。
"
"
尚、
"
勿論ですが、
貴方が　答申を、
下げられるなら。
"
"
当該の、
"
今回限定執行も　無根拠な、
ものと　なりますので、
当然ながら　ぐずれるやも、
知れませんがね。


という事で、

ご答申に　従い、
御記載の　一切を、
却下と　致します。

Comment: マイナス投票がおかしいと思えば自然とプラス投票されて増えていきます。私もそのように行動します。賛否両論だと拮抗します。しかしながらマイナスのまま維持されているということは消極的支持層であり、プラスに転じていないということは無関心とは言えません。

Comment: もちろん承認いただかなくても結構です。それも自由です。一応プラスになっていますし、私の意見は述べられているので削除もしません。このコミュニティの[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)にあるように、「プラス投票すると、その内容が「上」に移動してより多くの人に見られるようになります。」のでほかの良い回答でもっとプラスの投票を得るものもしくはマイナスの投票がつけば自然と見えない位置に下がることでしょう。

Comment: keitaro_so様、
"
ご返答　有難うございます。
"
"
所で、
"
間違えていたら　ご指摘して、
くださいね。
"
"
確か、
"
此方では　質問者に、
「調べろ、」等を、
求める　事は、
禁止事項では　なかったのですか？
"
"
では、
"
此を　水平展開して、
〉読みずらいと指摘される文章を直す
此を　求めるのも、
"
同精神からすれば、
禁止事項では　ないのですか？
"
"
もしかして、
"
此は　メタに、
別途　立てるべきですか？

Comment: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask にもありますが、まずは検索し調べましょうとあります。調査を尽くしていないと判断すれば、まずは検索することをコメントでおすすめすることもあります。

Comment: なのでコミュニティの運営で疑問に思ったらまずヘルプやメタを検索してみてください。その上で疑問を精査して質問してください。

Comment: keitaro_so様、
"
》自身言動こそが　最も、
》鋭利に、酷く、避けきれず、
》自身を　苛む。
と、
"
以前　確か、
お伝えを　しましたね。
"
"
〉まずは検索し調べましょうとあります。
"
オーディエンスの　皆様に、
そっくり　お返しします、
"
此の　討議の、
論点　其のもので、
"
添わぬ　ものを、
窘める　発言ですね。
"
"
詰まりは、
"
私に　向けた、
体で、
私以外に　発進する、
"
》マニュフェスト違反だ！！
との　答申ですね、
"
お立場か　あるのですかね？
解りました。

Comment: 〉検索し調べましょう
"
禁止発言ですよ？

Comment: すいません。検索して調べましょうがマニフェスト違反になる論拠がわかりませんでした。もう少しかみ砕いて分かりやすく説明してください。

Comment: @nouble さん、 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct には「ググればそんな簡単なことはすぐにわかるでしょ。」は好ましくない発言だと載っていますが、これは検索の推奨を好ましくないと言っているのではなく、相手をけなしているように受け取れる言い方が好ましくないと言っているのみです。実際その横に対比として書かれている好ましい言い方も、検索を推奨しています。

Comment: あれれ　矛盾してますね。
"
"
ヘルプ記載です、
"
〉質問と回答を投稿するだけであれば「信用度」は一切気にする必要はありません。
"
此も　矛盾ですね。
"
"
何故ですか？
"
此に限らず、
虚偽、矛盾、欺瞞、認知齟齬、
等　不適切発言を、
繰り返しますか？

Comment: 特に、
"
》自身は　テキストエディターすら、
》立ち上げないのに、
》他者には　綿密に、
》調べ上げろ、
とは、
どういった　思考でしょうか？
"
理解が　及ばず、
興味深いですね、
ご説明　願えますか？

Comment: ヘルプの記載の矛盾点はこのコメントで回答するには狭いため新しい質問をしていただければ幸いです。

Comment: テキストエディタ～云々については、マニフェストがライブラリを作るだからですね。ライブラリーを作るが第一で その為に誠実であれって

Comment: という立て付けになっています。

Comment: 質の良いライブラリを目指しているので、重複や質の悪いと判断される質問はクローズされます。